# Is there any purpose to the golden orbs that you can collect during loading screens?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Whilst playing episode 1 and some of episode 2 of the tyranny of King Washington DLC for Assassins Creed 3 I have been relentlessly collecting what I assume to be apples of Eden during the loading screens.

Is there any purpose to this or is it just to kill time while waiting for the game to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no real purpose for collecting those other than to just kill time while the game loads.

Comment: This is the same conclusion I have reached after collecting hundreds of them but I would like a source rather than speculation.